# Python TkInter: How can I get the canvas coordinates of the visible area of a scrollable canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, scroll, visible

I need to find out what the visible coordinates of a vertically scrollable canvas are using python and tkinter.

Let's assume I have a canvas that is 800 x 5000 pixels, and the visible, vertically scrollable window is 800x800. If I am scrolled all the way to the top of the canvas, I would like to have a function that, when run, would return something like:

```
x=0
y=0,
w=800
h=800
```

But if I were to scroll down and then run the function, I would get something like this:

```
x=0
y=350
w=800
h=800
```

And if I resized the window vertically to, say, 1000, I would get:

```
x=0
y=350
w=800
h=1000
```

I tried this code:

```
            self.canvas.update()
            print(f"X={self.canvas.canvasx(0)}")
            print(f"Y={self.canvas.canvasy(0)}")
            print(f"W={self.canvas.canvasx(self.canvas.winfo_width())}")
            print(f"H={self.canvas.canvasy(self.canvas.winfo_height())}")
```

But it gives me the size of the whole canvas, not the visible window inside the canvas.

I have tried searching for the answer, but am surprised not to have found anyone else with the same question. Perhaps I just don't have the right search terms.

Context for anyone who cares:

I am writing a thumbnail browser that is a grid of thumbnails. Since there may be thousands of thumbnails, I want to update the ones that are visible first, and then use a thread to update the remaining (hidden) thumbnails as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods `canvasx` and `canvasy` of the `Canvas` widget will convert screen pixels (ie: what's visible on the screen) into canvas pixels (the location in the larger virtual canvas).

You can feed it an x or y of zero to get the virtual pixel at the top-left of the visible window, and you can give it the width and height of the widget to get the pixel at the bottom-right of the visible window.

```
x0 = canvas.canvasx(0)
y0 = canvas.canvasy(0)
x1 = canvas.canvasx(canvas.winfo_width())
y1 = canvas.canvasy(canvas.winfo_height())
```

The canonical tcl/tk documentation says this about the `canvasx` method:

> pathName canvasx *screenx* ?*gridspacing*?: Given a window x-coordinate in the canvas *screenx*, this command returns the canvas x-coordinate that is displayed at that location. If *gridspacing* is specified, then the canvas coordinate is rounded to the nearest multiple of *gridspacing* units.

---

Here is a contrived program that will print the coordinates of the top-left and bottom right visible pixels every five seconds.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
canvas_frame = tk.Frame(root, bd=1, relief="sunken")
statusbar = tk.Label(root, bd=1, relief="sunken")

statusbar.pack(side="bottom", fill="x")
canvas_frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

canvas = tk.Canvas(canvas_frame, width=800, height=800, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
ysb = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
xsb = tk.Scrollbar(canvas_frame, orient="horizontal", command=canvas.xview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=ysb.set, xscrollcommand=xsb.set)

canvas_frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas_frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
ysb.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")
xsb.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="ew")

for row in range(70):
    for column in range(10):
        x = column * 80
        y = row * 80
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y, x+64, y+64, fill="gray")
        canvas.create_text(x+32, y+32, anchor="c", text=f"{row},{column}")

canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))

def show_coords():
    x0 = int(canvas.canvasx(0))
    y0 = int(canvas.canvasy(0))
    x1 = int(canvas.canvasx(canvas.winfo_width()))
    y1 = int(canvas.canvasy(canvas.winfo_height()))
    statusbar.configure(text=f"{x0},{y0} / {x1},{y1}")
    root.after(5000, show_coords)

show_coords()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I actually already tried this (you can see it in the code I used above). It does spit out some values for the height (what you called y1), but I could not work out what those values were because it certainly did not equal the height of the viewable area. But a little more examination shows that y1-y0 DOES gives me the height. Does that make sense?

(The scrollable frame is an instanced object in the window... could that be the issue?)

Comment: @bvz: since you didn't provide a working example I can only guess why it didn't work. It might be because you did it before the window was rendered on the screen. These methods work exactly as documented. This is precisely what these functions are for - to convert physical screen coordinates to virtual canvas coordinates.

Comment: thanks again for the help. I didn't post a working example because it was a pretty intricate and long amount of code. But I trust your explanation and so I think I will have to build a simplified example to start with and then slowly migrate it back into my code to see where I made my error. Your comments are much appreciated!